# OpenAI Codex: Bug: Codex cannot complete a small python program

Tags: codex

I am just trying out OpenAI codex and I can't get codex to complete a small python program. I give codex the prompt "can you write some python code to show four sliders a b c d in a separate macos window using a qwidget?" and codex writes about 30 lines and then stops. codex cant complete the code. I have seen this sort of problem on chatgpt caused by running out of tokens. but the codex code is not even thirty lines. Maybe the token limit on codex is smaller than on chatgpt? My conclusion at this point is that chatgpt is superior to codex as a coding tool but that can't be correct. I must be doing something wrong???